# Which Visual C++ DLLs are required?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction

I dislike having to distribute an installer for programs compiled with Microsoft's compiler. I prefer to use DLLs packaged in the same directory as the executable. So, what are the required DLLs for MSVC++ 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no one simple answer, because it'll depend on what dependencies you build into your program.

You might want to use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find what DLLs are actually used by any particular project you're distributing (though be aware that it will list things like `kernel32.dll` that you *can't* distirbute right along with those you need to). Before you distribute anything, you need to check license agreements to assure that you're allowed to do so.